# Join two tables and group by xyz

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
    ref       status

    abc     1
    abc     1
    abc     2
    abc     3
    abc     5(not in Table2)
    abc     5(not in Table2)
```

Table 2:

```
    ref          status

    abc     1
    abc     1
    abc     2
    abc     3
    abc             4(not in Table1)
    abc     4(not in Table1)
```

I want to join these two tables and perform a grouping so that the final result looks like this:

Resultant Table:
        ref       status

```
    abc     1
    abc     2
    abc     3
    abc     4
    abc     5
```

I have tried this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ref, Table1.status, Table2.ref, Table2.status
    FROM Table1, Table2
    GROUP BY Table1.ref, Table1.status, Table2.ref, Table2.status;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref, status
FROM
(
    SELECT ref, status
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ref, status
    FROM Table2
) x
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd87a/2)

Comment: @Ic. Mysql says that every derived table must have an alias, it worked in Ms. Access but mysql is where the error is.

Comment: @Alphy You must have caught my answer before I edited it and added the `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref, status
FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT ref, status
FROM Table2
```